# Forbid trait info to export in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [cyrildewit/laravel-page-view-counter](https://github.com/cyrildewit/laravel-page-view-counter) to count my pages views, the problem i'm facing is when I export my data as `CSV` my page counts will be included my table info while **they are stored in another table**.
here is how it's related to my table:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cyrildewit\PageVisitsCounter\Traits\HasPageVisitsCounter;

class Product extends Model
{
  use HasPageVisitsCounter;
```

That's all.

**Question:**

How can I prevent my counting result from being included my table data export file?

## UPDATE

`my export function`

```
public function export(Request $request) {
      $products = Product::all();
      Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products, $request) {
        $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products, $request){

          $ddd = $request->except('_token');

          $sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
          $sheet->row(1, $ddd);
        });
      })->export('csv');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: What are you using to export to CSV? Can it be configured to blacklist specific tables?

Comment: @mike I'm using laravel excel https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel (not sure it can be configured or not)

Comment: @fubar I don't use anything for my counting package all i use is my model I provided in my question `use HasPageVisitsCounter;`

Comment: @fubar I will update now

Comment: @fubar updated...

Comment: @fubar well? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Select only the fields that you want to include into the excel sheet, and convert to array:

```
$products = Product::select(['id', 'name', ...])->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: the issue is there is no column for my views in my table, as i said it is "Traits" `visits data are stored in different table.`

Comment: what columns you want to include into the excel file?

Comment: only my products table columns, i dont want visits column from another table be included

Comment: then only `whitelist` some columns into csv, but NOT passing the product model to `fromArray`